# Centos server change environment PWD

Tags: centos, environment-variables

I've a Centos Linux 6.5 server. If in the root (/home/wwwuser/) of this server I execute phpinfo.php, I notice that under "environment" PWD is set to /home/wwwuser/test/. I tried to rename that folder in test1, and the PWD was still set to that folder.

From what I read on google, this variable should return the current directory. So why if I execute it in the root it returns a subdirectory, even if it's a non-existing directory?

PHP Version 5.3.3
phpinfo.php code:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Comment: As is, answering this question is very difficult. Please provide more details about how the script is invoked (exact command line, naturally), its contents, versions of CentOS, PHP and any other components involved.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: @DanielB @ xR34P3Rx: I've added informations in the first post. Please note that wordpress in installed both in root and in "test" folder.

Comment: Sounds like enviroment problem. Login on the server as root. Find out what user your httpd server application is running under typing `lsof -i :80` in termal will usually display what user http server is running under if service is running on port 80. Then in terminal type `su - http_user_name_here` then after you login with that command type `echo $HOME` If it prints out `/wwwuser/test/` then that users home directory is not set correctly.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for your reply. httpds user is apache, but I can't executed "su - apache" because it says "this account is not currently available". From my webmin panel, apache home directory is set to "/var/www/", a different directory from "/home/wwwuser/", which is the real home directory of the server.

Comment: Try contacting the service provider. You need to login to web panel and change the home directory or login to server via eg. "ssh" then  find httpd.conf file and edit the home directory. Apache may also be setup using virtual hosts so you may need to find virtual hosts folder and edit the config in there manually. To change home directory. If you are using centos you may find config file under `/etc/httpd/conf` or `/usr/local/apache/conf`

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks once again for your reply. I've checked in '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf', and document root is correctly set to '/home/wwwuser/'. I'm on a dedicated server so I've access to everything.